# Should I apply for two jobs at the same company?

Tags: job-search, hiring-process, applications

I see this question in several different forms on this website, but I don't think they cover this particular scenario so I will ask anyway.

I'm a computer science student applying for Coop jobs in Canada. A company that I am a huge fan of has posted two jobs that I can apply two that are different, but are both development jobs that I can perform. The same person is receiving applications for both of these positions and I ***really*** would like to work for this company.

I'd like to know, would it hurt my chances of getting employed if I applied for both positions? Would it help? I am slightly more qualified for one of the positions but I'd like to do everything I can in order to get one of the two positions.

I'm concerned this may be reflect poorly on me if they realize I applied to both jobs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's perfectly fine to apply for two jobs at the same company if they're related (e.g. an engine developer and a GUI developer).

Personally I'd be more concerned it looks like I'm blindly applying for jobs and didn't notice they were at the same company. I would do my best to make it clear you knew you were applying for both:

- Some online recruitment forms allow you to mention if you've applied for another job
- If you are attaching a cover letter (you *are* attaching a cover letter aren't you) you should mention that you have applied for both jobs
- Otherwise if you make an interview, or get a chance to actually talk to someone there, it would be worth mentioning you are applying for both and which one you feel you're better suited for.

Even if you've done none of the above, and indeed the same person looks over both applications for both jobs, they will probably piece together you intentionally applied for both. Assuming they like you they may call you in for an interview for both, or simply ask which you'd prefer, otherwise they may have had a better applicant for job 1 and interview you only for job 2.